# Unable to re-authenticate (not refresh) using the same device key on AWS Cognito using .NET SDK

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, amazon-cognito, srp-protocol

#### Description

I am attempting to use the [aws-sdk-net-extensions-cognito](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net-extensions-cognito) library for Cognito authentication with device tracking enabled.  The cloud formation properties on the User Pool for this configuration are:

```
DeviceConfiguration:
    ChallengeRequiredOnNewDevice: false
    DeviceOnlyRememberedOnUserPrompt: false
```

I can successfully complete the following steps:

- User logins in the for the first time using `StartWithSrpAuthAsync` (generate a new device key)
- Use the `NewDeviceMetadata` to create a `DeviceVerifier` which includes `PasswordVerifier` and `Salt`
- Use this to `ConfirmDeviceAsync` which shows the new device for the user in the Cognito AWS Console dashboard
- As long as the device key is set on the user I can invoke `StartWithRefreshTokenAuthAsync` to successfully get refresh tokens

My issue at this point is that signing out and attempting to sign back in fails using the device key from the previous session.  I know I need to generate a new token but I shouldn't have to regenerate the device key on the same device.  Currently, when I tried to login using the device key from the previous session I get the following error:

```
"Incorrect username or password."
```

Here is my code for attempting to login using a local device key from the previous session:

```
user.Device = new CognitoDevice(
    new DeviceType { DeviceKey = deviceKey },
    user
);

var deviceVerifier = user.GenerateDeviceVerifier(DeviceInfo.DeviceGroupKey, password, DeviceInfo.DeviceKey);

authRequest = new InitiateSrpAuthRequest()
{
    Password = password,
    DeviceGroupKey = deviceGroupKey,
    DevicePass = deviceVerifier.PasswordVerifier,
    DeviceVerifier = deviceVerifier.Salt
};

// Fails with 400 error mentioned above
var authResponse = await user.StartWithSrpAuthAsync(authRequest);
```

I have a feeling it's related to the creation of `new InitiateSrpAuthRequest()` and the values I am providing.  I was unable to find documentation around these parameter values.  I was assuming `DevicePass` is the `PasswordVerifier` created by `GenerateDeviceVerifier` and  `DeviceVerifier` is the `Salt` from `GenerateDeviceVerifier` but the key names are confusing?

**TLDR:  What values are expected for `DevicePass` and `DeviceVerifier` or am I doing something else incorrectly.**

#### AWS .NET SDK and/or Package version used

`Amazon.Extensions.CognitoAuthentication 2.5.2` (latest)

#### Targeted .NET Platform

.NET Framework 4.8 & .NET 6.0

#### Operating System and version

Windows 10/11

#### Expected Behavior

I can re-authenticate a user (not refresh) but use the same device key which will not create a new device for that user as long as they are on the same machine.

#### Current Behavior

- Initial token/device key creation works
- Token refresh works when device key is provided
- Logging out and logging back in fails due `"Incorrect username or password."`

  - The only difference with the initial auth is the parameters we pass to `InitiateSrpAuthRequest()`
  - The initial login we only provide the `Password`
  - Reoccurring logins where a local device key is found in the cache we provide `Password`, `DeviceGroupKey`, `DevicePass` and `DeviceVerifier` which fails

#### References

The issue follows a very similar flow outlined in this other old issue https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net-extensions-cognito/issues/44 on GitHub but I am getting a different error at the final step.

Another user on the same thread [commented](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net-extensions-cognito/issues/44#issuecomment-841617784) with the **SAME ERROR** message but his remedy did not seem to help me.  He is questioning the signature on [GenerateDeviceVerifier()](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net-extensions-cognito/blob/master/src/Amazon.Extensions.CognitoAuthentication/Util/AuthenticationHelper.cs#L167).  I have tried `username` and `deviceKey`.